# How to flatten the dataset properly

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like this
[image]

The problem here is i want to have `General_officers_0_Name` , `General_officers_0_Title`, `General_officers_0_YearBorn` and same for the others ones with different values like `MAtainance_name_type_work_ty` like this for the nested data type how to do this please help to solve this?
If this question is asked previously and contains the answer please remind to link with that.

The output of `print (df.head().to_dict(orient='list'))`  is
[image]

Comment: What is `print (df.head().to_dict(orient='list'))` ?

Comment: some have the data and some are showing NaN values